# How to include an image link in wordpress menus?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress twentyfourteen theme, here i just want to add image links instead of text links from admin panel as dynamically in **wp_nav_menu**.

See my code that i'm expecting output sample,

```
<ul>
    <li ><a href="http://www.example.org" title="Home"><img src="home.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li ><a href="http://www.example.com" title="About"><img src="about.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li ><a href="http://www.example.in" title="Blog"><img src="blog.png" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-images/). I believe this is exactly that you need.

Also, Arun's suggestion is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a extra css class and in that class name write ur image code.
2. U can add that extra css class here Appearance->menus : there u find CSS Classes (optional)
3. If u didn't find it then, click screen option in the top right hand corner (near help), there u can enable css classes, description, etc.,

Comment: you are telling idea for adding background image, but am asking front image link..anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: @Bharathi06 Yes, This is the answer. I vote it. Simply, what you can do is. Add menu as like you add from dashboard. Then click the arrow to collapse the menu bar properties. then add you css code in `optional css`. After in the front-end view. You can do your css-tricks.